# Bootstrap Modal Freezes Page After Closing

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Not sure why, but my Bootstrap Modal is freezing my screen after I hit the Close button.  Bootstrap version is 3.3.6

**Modal code:**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" !important>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Message</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" ng-model="msg.message" required autofocus style="max-width: 100%;">{{msg.message}}</textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="controller.edit(msg)">Edit And Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Button click calling modal:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
```

**Method being called on close:**

```
public edit(message) {
    console.log(message);
    this.$http.put(`api/causemessage`, message).then((res) => {
        this.$state.reload();
    });
}
```

If anyone can help diagnose this problem, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: A fiddle will be nice to have

Comment: You should use angular bootstrap instead of bootstrap with jQuery

Comment: @SiddharthPandey My entire project is hundreds of files long.  I gave you everything I have relevant to the modal itself besides the core bootstrap files.

I can also use a bunch of different modals and methods, no offense, I'm just looking for a solution for my current approach for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the  following script in method you call on close..

$('#myModal').modal('hide');

Comment: Worked, thank you!
For those of you who cannot get jQuery to recognize .modal.
You can do this.
(<any>$('#myModal')).modal('hide');

Answer (score 4):

**For Bootstrap 4**

Not sure if anybody still looking for answer for this issue. Had a similar problem. I used jquery to

```
$("#modalId").modal('hide'); 
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

and this only close the modal and remove the backdrop(shadow), however, the page is still frozen. This is because the  is changed to `<body class='modal-open'>`
Need to add another jquery to remove the class='modal-open' to make the whole page scrollable again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Bootstrap 4.

I took the following steps:

1. Assign the Id to button instead of data-target
2. Trigger modal using jquery

   ```
    $('#button-id').on('click', function() {
     $('#modal-id').modal('show'); 
        });
   ```
3. Then, followed this answer [bootstrap 4 modal-backdrop style (specific modal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755130/bootstrap-4-modal-backdrop-style-specific-modal)

My issues is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem and my issue was after modal hide screen freezes and user can't do anything . Below is the code that worked for me.

```js
$("#modalId").modal('hide'); 
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

in Angular with Bootstrap, i faced the same issue. freezing occurs when `<modal-container> </modal-container>` is not removed, even when we call `bsModalRef.hide()`

i used below method as a work-around and it solved my issue. use the below code after `bsModalRef.hide()`

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("freeze-resolve");
var i;
if(element && element.length>0){
  for (i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    element[i].parentElement.remove();
  }
}
```

`freeze-resolve` class should be used with `bsModalService.show()`

ex:

```
  this.ModalRef = this.bsModalService.show(modalToShow, {
  class: 'modal-lg modal-class freeze-resolve',
  animated: true,
  keyboard: true,
  backdrop: true,
  ignoreBackdropClick: true
});
```