# bootstrap 4 modal-backdrop style (specific modal)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4

I wondered how can I change the colour of the modal backdrop (not the background colour of modal) for specific modal.

The colour can be changed if I use "shown.bs.modal" with some delays. But I want to change the backdrop colour immediately.
Hope somebody can help. Thank you.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
                $(".modal-backdrop").css('background', '#fb0404');
            })
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/rae0724/pen/oqmPmY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a custom class to the body *before* the modal is opened, and then remove the class when it's closed...

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('body').addClass("example-open");
}).on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('body').removeClass("example-open");
})
```

The you just need the CSS for the custom color applied to the backdrop.

```
.example-open .modal-backdrop {background-color:red;}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/oNKsVikW6n

Answer (score 2):

Use div modal-content instead of modal-backdrop, like this :

```
$(".modal-content").css('background', 'red');
```

UPDATE :

Add in your css :

```
.modal-backdrop.show{background-color: red;}
```

Comment: hi, i want to change the background colour of modal-backdrop, not the background colour of the modal.

Comment: but for specific modal, not for all modals.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, I think you can change your CSS to this:

```
.modal-content {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: hi, i want to change the background colour of modal-backdrop, not the background colour of the modal.

Comment: Do you mean something like an [overlay?](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_backdrop&stacked=h)