# Bootstrap 4 Modal without backdrop

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I try to display a Bootstrap 4 modal, but without a backdrop.

In order to do this I have try this, without success:

```
.modal.right. modal-backdrop.show {
   background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

If I try this, it works (but it is not applied to 'right' classes only):

```
modal-backdrop.show {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Here is the example for testing : https://codepen.io/cdemez/pen/abdmxXZ

If someone has an idea to solve the problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bootstrap 4 modal-backdrop style (specific modal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755130/bootstrap-4-modal-backdrop-style-specific-modal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing a particular modal's backdrop can not be styled with plain CSS. Bootstrap doesn't define such a thing.

With the help of CSS you can change backdrop style globally(applicable to all modal's backdrop).

Modal backdrop element is outside the `modal` class. So you can target element with the help of jquery.

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
//parent element of backdrop is `body`
    $('body').addClass("example-open");
}).on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('body').removeClass("example-open");
})
```

then you can use css

```css
.example-open .modal-backdrop {background-color:red !important;}
```

Working example : https://www.codeply.com/p/WBAMNC7G5m

Comment: Thanks, but I wish a CSS only solution!

Comment: This is not possible by css, because bootstrap doesn't provide any thing like that. This is the only solution here.
with the help of css, you can change global class of backdrop that will be applicable on all modal's backdrop.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I have no other solution. Have you noticed that if I set the background as transparent, when closing the modal the backdrop reappear for a short time ?

Comment: That might be because of `fade` animation. Try once by removing `fade` class from modal.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, you want the modal to appear with no backdrop. Looking at your HTML you have the tag as

```
 <div class="modal right fade" data-backdrop="hidden" id="exampleModal" tabindex="" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

The data-drop attribute is a boolean value so change it to false and it should remove the backdrop.

Like this:

```
<div class="modal right fade" data-backdrop="false" id="exampleModal" tabindex="" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Thanks, but data-backdrop="false" hide the backdrop, but also make it non-clickable. ie. "static". I only want to hide it, but when I click outside it, the modal should close ;-)